# How to adjust google sheet view depending on variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with the following script that adjusts the view rows according to a variable:

```
function ConditionalHideRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var maxrows = sheet.getMaxRows()
          for (var i = 0; i < maxrows; ++i) {            
              if (sheet.getRange(maxrows-i,4).getValue() == "var1" )  {
                sheet.hideRows(maxrows-i,1)  
              }
            else
            {
              sheet.showRows(maxrows-i,1)
            }

       }
}
```

I want to pass a variable in the page that adjusts the view:
for example

- if I pass var1 in the URL for example, the rows containing var1 are
  shown, all the others are not
- if I pass var2 in the URL for example,
  the rows containing var2 are shown, all the others are not

etc

Comment: I have tried function doGet(e)  
  var viewmode = e.parameter.view but doesn't seem to work when I am passing ....?view = "a"

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried function doGet(e) var viewmode = e.parameter.view but doesn't seem to work when I am passing ....?view = "a"

To pass "a" to the `doGet()` in the URL query it like this `...?view=a`; no need in the apostrophes.

Sample

```
function doGet(e){
  var parameter = e.parameter;
  if(parameter.view){ //check off the view type was passed
    ConditionalHideRow(parater.view);
  };
}
function ConditionalHideRow(condition){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var maxrows = sheet.getDataRange().getHeight();
      for (var i = 0; i < maxrows; ++i) {            
          if (sheet.getRange(maxrows-i,4).getValue() == condition )  {
            sheet.hideRows(maxrows-i,1);  
          }
          else
          {
            sheet.showRows(maxrows-i,1);
          };
   }
}
```

This is off topic, but `getDataRange().getHeight()` i my experience is better to use, since  `getMaxRows()` will return you a total number of rows, even if they are empty.

By default there is a 1000 empty rows, and even though you don't have any data there, you will still loop through it. `getDataRange().getHeight()` will give you a number of the last row where any piece of data appears.

Also, I am just curious, why are you looping backwards through the rows?